# QEMU Booting for kernel developement not working when using tcp 2222:22 to copy things

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, linux-kernel, qemu

I am learning how to implement my own system call in linux kernel by following:

- [Syscall Guide](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eashriram/Courses/Old/2017/CS300/assignments/assignments/prj4/Project4-SysCalls.pdf)
- [Custom Kernel Guide](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eashriram/Courses/Old/2017/CS300/assignments/assignments/prj4/Guide_CustomKernel.pdf)

for getting QEMU set up.

In the end, it tells us to run the following command to Redirect port 2222 on the host OS to the QEMU VM's port 22 which will let me copy files between QEMU and my linux:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 64M -hda ../debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 - append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" -kernel arch/ x86_64/boot/bzImage -nographic -net nic,vlan=1 -net user,vlan=1 -redir tcp: 2222::22
```

But I get the follwing error on my terminal when I run the code:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -: invalid option
```

Help me out, I am a beginner. Thanks

Comment: You have put an extra whitespace between `-` and `append` in your command line. `-append` should be single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your command line: "- append"   -- you have an extra space between the "-" and the "append". QEMU command line options are generally of the form "-something". If you put a space in the middle then QEMU won't recognize what you've given it.

If you're following a tutorial and a command it gives you doesn't work then it's often a good idea to check it carefully for minor typos, or to copy-and-paste the command from the tutorial and try that.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for this!! Can you please help me a little more. After removing the space, i get the following error :
qemu-system-x86_64: -redir tcp:: The -redir option is deprecated. Please use '-netdev user,hostfwd=...' instead.
qemu-system-x86_64: -net nic,vlan=1: 'vlan' is deprecated. Please use 'netdev' instead.
qemu-system-x86_64: -net user,vlan=1: Invalid host forwarding rule 'tcp:' (Bad host port separator)

Comment: Again, keep checking your command line. You have another stray extra space in it. (The "deprecated" part you can ignore for now: this command line will stop working on a later QEMU version but is OK on the one you are using.)

Comment: hey!! that worked. Thanks, Also now when i run:  scp -P 2222 newcheck root@localhost:~ . as said in tutorial to copy the newcheck file in the QEMU, it shows the following error: ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
lost connection. What's the problem now?